# How to source /etc/profile or /etc/bash.bashrc file using Ansible

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I am trying to source  /etc/profile or /etc/bash.bashrc using Ansible but keep getting error message.

```
TASK [Source Profile] 
*********************************************************************

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "source /etc/profile", _
    "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

my code is

```
- name: Source Profile
  shell: source /etc/bash.bashrc
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

I tried many other things.

such as `command: source /etc/bash.bashrc`
(Also tried `/etc/profile` instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc`)

How can I source or what is the best way to apply this?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Ansible to suggest a solution, but the problem is that you are trying to execute a program whose name is literally the two words "source /etc/profile".

Comment: I would have to agree with [user:chepner] about the shell command.  from a simple documentation lookup, the `shell` command should be the executable to be run itself, so like `shell: source' and then use args for any space delimited arguments to pass.  Quick Google Groups search came up with this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/PNNpxY4ItSo

Comment: Or you could remove the `args` optional command and put the full string in `shell`.  Such as `shell: source /etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Additional alternative would be to do `command: source /home/ubuntu/.bash_profile  executable=/bin/bash` as a one-liner instead of `shell`

Comment: But you are aware that this task basically makes no sense? Sourced values will be lost immediately after this task ends.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the files you are trying to source exist, from your error message "**No such file or directory**" is telling you that files don't exist, for example, this works locally:

```
# ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local test.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: test source profile
      shell: source /etc/bashrc
      register: output 
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash

    - debug: msg="{{ output }}"
```

In this case, is trying to source `/etc/bashrc`

Also, notice the `register: output` and:

```
- debug: msg="{{ output }}"
```

That will register the output of the command into a variable named `output` and print its contents, give a try, it could give you more ideas about what is wrong.

It will output something like:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local test.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test source profile] *****************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************     
ok: [localhost] => {                      
    "msg": {                              
        "changed": true,                  
        "cmd": "source /etc/bashrc",      
        "delta": "0:00:00.004553",        
        "end": "2017-09-22 21:15:24.654777",                                         
        "rc": 0,                          
        "start": "2017-09-22 21:15:24.650224",                                       
        "stderr": "",                     
        "stdout": "",                     
        "stdout_lines": [],               
        "warnings": []                    
    }                                     
} 

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: file is there for sure. All Ubuntu at least should have /etc/profile and/or /etc/bash.bashrc. Also when I run the command locally, it works fine.

Comment: double check, maybe you have it locally but not in your remote system, not for nothing you are getting the error from ansible "No such file or directory"

Comment: I did test and it is there for sure @nbari . I tested by trying to edit the file. it was able to add a line. For some reason, it is just not sourcing.

Comment: @automateable I updated the answer so that you can have an idea about how to debug the output of the command, give a try should give you some hints.